# Error upgrading grails app to 2.3.7

Tags: grails, groovy, lucene, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I have recently upgraded my Grails application from 2.1.1 to 2.3.7.
It's showing some exceptions with searchable plugin.
I am using searchable:0.6.6

Exception looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Charu\.grails\2.3.7\projects\jobjoos\plugins\searchable-0.6.6\src\java\grails\plugin\searchable\internal\compass\config\EnvironmentSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:25: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Charu\.grails\2.3.7\projects\jobjoos\plugins\searchable-0.6.6\src\java\grails\plugin\searchable\internal\compass\search\DefaultSuggestQueryMethod.java:31: package org.apache.lucene.analysis does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
```

Can anyone help me on this, about what's causing it to fail and how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this:

```
Use the above dependency declaration in your BuildConfig.groovy file and then add

mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

since this is now required

I had got around it in the past by adding this to my dependencies

```
dependencies {

        compile("org.compass-project:compass:2.2.0")
}
```

Comment: Hi @vahid: adding these gives me  UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES      ::org.compass-project#compass;2.2.1: configuration not found in org.compass-project#compass;2.2.1: 'master'. It was required from org.grails.plugins#searchable;0.6.6 compile

Comment: "C:\Users\Charu\.grails\2.3.7\projects\jobjoos"
delete this folder and start application again, it will try to create fresh dependency , i suggest you take back up of "jobjoos" as well before doing this  , upgrading grail project is always a mess i try not to unless really needed.

Comment: the org.compass was something I had been using, upon searchable updates they recently added the mavenRepo which has all of the dependencies. I would suggest attempting a fresh project on 2.3.7 with searchable -get it working then figure out whats going wrong in yours.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the searchable version from 0.6.6 to 0.6.5, then it works fine.